# CABasicAnimation on strokeEnd

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I have a `CAShapeLayer` in form of a square and I set the `width` to be 2.0f.

I would like to animate its `strokeEnd` and for that I use a `CABasicAnimation` like so:

```
CABasicAnimation *stroke = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
stroke.fromValue = @(0);
stroke.toValue = @(1); 
stroke.repeatCount = 1;
stroke.duration = 10.0f;
stroke.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
[myLayer addAnimation:stroke forKey:nil];
```

And it works. From the book by Matt Neuberg, I understand that we could omit the `toValue` and `fromValue` altogether by:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
..
..
[CATransaction commit];
```

His example was, however, based on `transform`. And I am trying to achieve the same instead with `strokeEnd`.

The best I can do is to set the `strokeEnd` within `CATransaction` block to either 1 or 0 and set the `fromValue` correspondingly. Other words I don't seem to be able omit both `toValue` and `endValue` on animating `strokeEnd` - I need at least one of them (i.e., `fromValue` or `toValue`).

So my question is, how could I be able to animate `strokeEnd` without needing to use `toValue` and `fromValue` at all?

Thanks.

Comment: The property needs to change, that's about it.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Doesn't seem to be a tiny hint to the answer, however.

Comment: Why don't you want to set `fromValue` and `toValue`? That strikes me as the most intuitive approach to specify precisely what you want to animate the `strokeEnd` from and to.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two very different issues at play here:

1. If you change one of your layer's animatable properties (i.e. not with a `CABasicAnimation`, but rather changing the layer's properties in code, directly) Core Animation may apply implicit animations to the layer (a relatively fast animation, but an animation nonetheless). For example, if you change `myLayer.opacity`, Core Animation may automatically apply implicit animations to fade this effect. Likewise if you directly change `myLayer.strokeEnd`, it may animate the change of the stroke end (you'll see it quickly drawing the line, rather than just immediately appearing).

   By using `[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES]`, you can instruct Core Animation to not perform these implicit animations that may apply when you change the layer's properties directly. By using `[CATransaction setDisableActions:NO]`, you will re-enable the implicit animations.
2. When you create a `CABasicAnimation`, there are `fromValue`, `toValue`, and `byValue` properties (which according to the documentation, "All are optional, and no more than two should be non-`nil`."). Frequently you'll see animations that specify both the `fromValue` and `toValue`. But you want, you can specify one, and Core Animation will determine what the others should be.

   For example, let's assume you just created a `CAShapeLayer` (and by default, `strokeEnd` is `1.0`). Then if I want to animate `strokeEnd` from 0 to 100%, you can just use:

   ```
   CABasicAnimation *stroke = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
   stroke.fromValue = @(0.0);
   stroke.duration = 1.0f;
   [myLayer addAnimation:stroke forKey:nil];
   ```

   Note, I did not have to specify the `toValue` of `@(1.0)`, because it will automatically default to the current value of `myLayer.strokeEnd` (which happens to be 1.0 in this example).

Where these two disparate aspects of Core Animation interact is when you're writing an animation using `CABasicAnimation` in which you not only want to specify the animation, but you also want to alter the properties of the layer, directly, right before the animation commences.

For example, if I added a `CAShapeLayer` as a `sublayer`, but wanted to animate the drawing of the first half of it (i.e. animate `strokeEnd` from `0.0` to `0.5`), you might theoretically want to (a) specify `myLayer.shapeEnd` to be the final value (e.g. `0.5`); and (b) create a `CABasicAnimation` with a `fromValue` of `@(0.0)` (but you could omit `toValue` because we've already set the layer's `shapeEnd` to the appropriate value). But, going back to point 1 at the start of my answer, when we set a layer property directly, such as `myLayer.shapeEnd`, you  might want to `setDisableActions` to `YES`, so there's no attempt at any implicit animation (given that we're about to specify the actual desired animation with the `CABasicAnimation`).

```
// set the layer's strokeEnd directly (with no implicit animation)

[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
myLayer.strokeEnd = 0.5;
[CATransaction setDisableActions:NO];

// now animate the layer's stroke end from 0.0 to the final value,
// which, because we didn't specify `toValue`, will default to the
// current value of `myLayer.strokeEnd` (which we happened to set
// right above)

CABasicAnimation *stroke = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
stroke.fromValue = @0.0;
stroke.duration = 1.0f;
[myLayer addAnimation:stroke forKey:nil];
```

In practice, I find the `setDisableActions` is often unnecessary, but technically, if you're setting the layer's properties and you want to ensure that there's no implicit animation initiated, you may wish to use `setDisableActions`, as shown above.

But, as you might infer from this discussion, the fact that we do not need to set `toValue` is not a direct result of using `CATransaction` or its method `setDisableActions`. The `toValue` is not needed in this example because we set the layer's `strokeEnd` before starting the animation. We just happen to use `CATransaction setDisableActions` to ensure there's no implicit animation initiated when changing layer properties directly.